How to create HD keys for ECDSA P256 in TypeScript?
I'm trying to build an algorithm, that generates HD keys based on bip32 mnemonic phrase for ECDSA_P256 (i'm building a wallet for Flow network). I googled some samples and tried to use it, but it produced some strange result. First of all, key pair didn't match the one that I generated via official tools like CLI and wallet. Secondly public key was shorter then the one I receive from official tools. What am I doing wrong, and how to make it work correctly? Here is the code:
import * as bip39 from 'bip39';
import { BIP32Factory } from 'bip32';
import * as ecc from 'tiny-secp256k1'; 
import { ECPairFactory } from 'ecpair';
import { payments } from 'bitcoinjs-lib';

const bip32 = BIP32Factory(ecc);
const ECPair = ECPairFactory(ecc);

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
console.log("Mnemonic:", mnemonic);

const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);

const root = bip32.fromSeed(seed);

const derivationPath = "m/44'/539'/0'/0/0";
const child = root.derivePath(derivationPath);

const keyPair = ECPair.fromPrivateKey(child.privateKey!!);

const { address } = payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey });
console.log("Address:", address);
console.log("Private Key:", keyPair.privateKey!!.toString('hex'));
console.log("Public Key:", keyPair.publicKey.toString('hex'));


...First of all, key pair didn't match the one that I generated via official tools...: ECDSA_P256 and tiny-secp256k1 seem to conflict. ... Secondly public key was shorter then the one I receive from official tools...: your code may generate a compressed key. Post the reference data (private key, public key, address) generated by the official tools for a given mnemonic.
